# GridView's ItemContainerStyle and selection states

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm trying to change the appearance of gridview items when they are selected.
(Before, I used a trick with an IsSelected property in the ViewModel object bound to the containing grid and a bool-to-color converter, but I recognize that it is bad)

To do so, I do:

```xml
    <GridView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemContainerStyle}" ...> ...
```

and

```xml
    <Style x:Key="GridViewItemContainerStyle" TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background)" Storyboard.TargetName="itemGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedSwiping"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selecting"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background)" Storyboard.TargetName="itemGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedSwiping"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselecting"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <Grid ... x:Name="itemGrid">
                              <!-- HERE MY DATA TEMPLATE -->
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

When I run the app, the items are Black (as in the "normal" state). But selecting them does not turn them into White. Where am I wrong?

Moreover, it there a way to set "ItemContainerStyle" without having it to "overwrite" the "ItemTemplate" ???

Answer (score 4):

You **DataTemplate** should be inside the **ItemTemplate** property of the **GridView** element in your page's XAML. Make a separate XAML file (ResourceDictionary), for example *CustomStyles.xaml*. Reference it in *App.xaml* like this:

```
    <Application.Resources>
    <!-- Application-specific resources -->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="PathToCustomStyles.xaml" />             
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>          
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

You can find on MSDN the default template for **GridViewItem** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709915.aspx), under the **Default style** section (second, longer XAML).

Copy that and paste it into *CustomStyles.xaml*. Just give it some key like:

```
<Style TargetType="GridViewItem" x:Key="CustomGridViewItemStyleWithWhiteSelectionBackground">...
```

As you can see, **Selected** visual state changes the opacity of three targets, **SelectionBackground**, **SelectedBorder** and **SelectedCheckMark**. So, these elements are not visible in **Normal** state because their opacity is zero. Find those three elements down below, and change their properties if needed. For the background change the **Fill** property of the **SelectionBackground** rectangle:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="SelectionBackground"
    Margin="4"
    Fill="White"
    Opacity="0" />
```

Now, when the selection occurs, this element's opacity will be changed to 1 and since you set it's Fill to be white, the background of the selected item will be white. And don't forget to reference this style in the definition of the GridView:

```
<GridView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomGridViewItemStyleWithWhiteSelectionBackground}" ...>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    ...define your template here...
    </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

**Edit:**

This is the expanded style XAML, probably more suitable for some more complicated style changes. If you want to change only the background, you should take the first style from that MSDN link above under the **Default style** section, and just edit this (and give it some style key, so you don't overwrite the default one):

```
SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
```